# Building pentaho-platform from github

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

i have cloned github repository after tht i have created the following projects.

pentaho-platform-api

pentaho-platform-assembly

pentaho-platform-core

pentaho-platform-extensions

pentaho-platform-repository

pentaho-platform-scheduler

pentaho-user-console

but i am not able to add jar files in build path because cloned repository folder "pentaho-platform" doesnt contain any folder like jar.

if any one knows how to build it then please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Not quite sure about building the platform, I usually use CBF - http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cbf.html any reason for building from source, if you want the latest there's always ci.pentaho.com

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to run ant in order to build and resolve dependencies.

From the pentaho-platform folder, run ant -f dev_build.xml dev-rebuild.

Comment: I upvoted this answer and just thought I'd add a note... I tried this on Windows and ended up getting "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long". My pentaho-platform directory was in C:\coding\eclipse\workspace\pentaho-platform\ so to fix it, I created a symlink to it at C:\p and ran it from there and then it worked with no problems. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

First, please make sure clone from https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform

Copy file `dev_build.xml` to `build.xml`

And then run `ant dev-resolve` (please install ANT before)

The last thing: `ant dev-build`

That's all!

**EDIT**

Pentaho BI after build is in that folder: `assembly/bin/stage/biserver-ce`

Answer (score 1):

Full instructions are in these 2 places:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/02.+Exploring+the+Pentaho+Repository+in+2.0

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/03.+Checking+Out+and+Building+Projects+in+5.0

Depending on your version etc. ( and surrounding pages )

Comment: I tried right now. It worked for me, though it takes a lot of time to fill the Ivy Cache required. For the whole project setup and ressources download, it took me 4 hours.

Comment: More recently, they are using Maven not Ivy https://github.com/pentaho/maven-parent-poms/wiki